# SQL Server List Foreign Key Information

Tags: sql-server, join, schema, metadata

I need to get a list of all foreign keys, which schema/table they belong to, which schema/table they reference, and the name of the column that is referenced. This is what I have so far but the column being returned is not correct. Any ideas?

```
select distinct
    ParentSchema.name as PARENT_SCHEMA_NAME,
    ParentTable.name as PARENT_TABLE_NAME,
    TheSchema.name as TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TheTable.name as TABLE_NAME,    
    fks.name as KEY_NAME ,
    COL_NAME(ParentTable.OBJECT_ID,fkcs.constraint_column_id) as CHILD_COLUMN_NAME
from 
    sys.foreign_keys fks
inner join
    Sys.foreign_key_columns fkcs
on
    fks.parent_object_id = fkcs.parent_object_id
inner join
    sys.tables TheTable
on
    fks.parent_object_id = TheTable.object_id
inner join
    sys.tables ParentTable
on
    fks.referenced_object_id = ParentTable.object_id
inner join
    sys.schemas TheSchema
on
    TheTable.schema_id = TheSchema.schema_id
inner join
    sys.schemas ParentSchema
on
    ParentTable.schema_id = ParentSchema.schema_id
order by
    fks.name
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following script for getting the information I need related to foreign keys, could be useful for you too:

```
SELECT    KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        , KCU1.TABLE_NAME AS FK_TABLE_NAME 
        , KCU1.COLUMN_NAME AS FK_COLUMN_NAME 
        , KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS REFERENCED_CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        , KCU2.TABLE_NAME AS REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME 
        , KCU2.COLUMN_NAME AS REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS RC 
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU1 ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU2 ON KCU2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME AND KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION
WHERE KCU1.TABLE_NAME = 'PurchaseOrders'
```

For the table `PurchaseOrders`, in the `WideWorldImporters` database it shows the following information:

[image]

You can check out all the columns included in the [information_schema.referential_constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/referential-constraints-transact-sql) and 
[information_schema.key_column_usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/key-column-usage-transact-sql) and then change the query to fit your needs.